# How do I play Wave Rider on Steam?

Tags: 20.04, games, steam

I am trying to play [Wave Rider](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1316310/WAVE_RIDER/) on Steam but the game glitches out when I open it.

Does anyone know how to get it to run?

Comment: Are you sure that's not a Windows only game?  The games that say "steam" are the ones that run on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there aren't any reports of the game on [protonDB](https://www.protondb.com/app/1316310). That usually means that no one tried to play it on Linux or that the devs haven't created support for the game in proton. The best thing to do is to leave a report; perhaps could it make devs aware of the situation.

As for the Steam page, it is clearly written that only Windows is supported.

The best thing to do is make a report, contact the devs and wait, sadly.